# Unable to Export Diagram to Image Files Using StarUML

Tags: uml, staruml

I am using StarUML 2.1.2. I created Sequence Diagram. I want to export it as image (.jpg or .png). But when I exported it, the image file didn't exist. And when I checked the Export As dialog, there is no .jpg or .png filetypes. How can I export my diagram into image file?

Here is the screenshot :
[image]

Comment: Had the same issue on mac.

Answer (score 6):

I downloaded version 2.7.0 and had the same problem. 
The solution is:

1. First you must have a connection to the internet.
2. Open the start uml application after you connected.
3. Create the Projek.
4. Click File > Export Diagram as.. > PNG

Comment: So, they just need to export it instead of saving?

Answer (score 3):

I know it's late, but if someone else has the same problem:

1. try to disconnect and reconnect to internet
2. close and reopen starUML
3. retry to export diagram as png/jpeg/svg

Answer (score 2):

Just had the same problem.
In my case I was able to export as SVG, open it (it used IE by default) and right click -> Save image as -> PNG.

The question was asked a couple of weeks ago, but I hope it can help someone looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting StarUML has solved the problem for me.

Comment: same thing for me

Answer (score 1):

**Save you diagram first** in one of UML or starUML formats. Then do the export.

If it still doesn't work try this:

**1. Save** your diagram first- *Don't close startUML program without saving your diagrams, you will loose them*. Then close starUML program.

**2. Re-start** the starUML program and then open your diagram/model. Or navigate to the folder where you saved your work and double click it-this will automatically open starUML loaded with your diagram.

**3. Now try to export** the file in your desired format...This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

check `File -> Export Diagram As -> PNG`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if anyone still face the problem after doing any step that already in the comment

1. try restart the node in debug menu
2. and try export the diagram again

this solved my problem.